# Is there a way to hide() unmatched search elements using mark.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, search, highlight

Is there a way to hide() unmatched search elements using mark.js? After reading the documentation I initially thought that I could use the "noMatch" option to write a custom function to hide the parent div of unmatched text, but it's not working as hoped for.

For example, if I am using mark.js to search and highlight "Lorem" in the following:

```
   <div class="panel-body context">
        <h2>Lorem</h2>
        <div>
           <p>ipsum</p>
           <p>lorem</p>
        </div>
        <h2>ipsum</h2>
        <div>
           <p>ipsum</p>
           <p>lorem</p>
        </div>
     </div>
```

How can I get it to only return the matched elements like so?

```
 <div class="panel-body context">
    <h2><span="highlight">Lorem</span><h2>
    <div>
       <p><span="highlight">lorem</span></p>
    </div>
    <div>
       <p><span="highlight">lorem</span></p>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Here's my current code block:

```
$(function() {

    var mark = function() {

        // Read the keyword
        var keyword = $("input[name='search-keyword']").val();

        // Determine selected options
        var options = {
            "element": "span",
            "className": "highlight",
            "separateWordSearch": false,
            "noMatch": function(term) {
                term.hide(); // WHERE I HOPED I COULD ADD HIDE LOGIC
            }
        }
        // Remove previous marked elements and mark
        // the new keyword inside the context
        $(".panel-body context").unmark({
            done: function() {
                $(".panel-body context").mark(keyword, options);
            }
        });
    };

    $("input[name='search-keyword']").on("input", mark);

});
```

**EDIT** Here's my altered [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Connor1988/vpav6tL1/538/) from the mark.js examples for a better example of what I'm attempting to do. Thanks for any assistance ahead of time!

Comment: You could use the `:not` psuedo-selector `.panel-body h2:not(.highlight), .panel-body p:not(.highlight) { display: none; }`

Comment: @Rob M. I appreciate your time, but I don't understand where I could put that logic using the mark.js library.  Are you thinking that it would go after the `done: function()` or?

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {
  var mark = function() {
    // Read the keyword
    var keyword = $("input[name='keyword']").val();
    var keyword2 = $("input[name='keyword2']").val();
    // Remove previous marked elements and mark
    // the new keyword inside the context
    $(".context").unmark({
      done: function() {
        $(".context").mark(keyword).mark(keyword2, {className: 'secondary'});
        $("#binddata").text(keyword);
      }
    });
  };
  $("input[name^='keyword']").on("input", mark);
});
```

```css
mark {
  padding: 0;
  background-color:yellow;
}
mark.secondary {
  padding: 0;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.3.6/superhero/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/mark.js/8.6.0/jquery.mark.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" name="keyword"><input type="text" name="keyword2">
<span id="binddata">Bind Character</span>
<div class="context">
The fox went over the fence
<h2>Lorem<h2>
        <div>
           <p>ipsum</p>
           <p>lorem</p>
        </div>
        <h2>ipsum</h2>
        <div>
           <p>ipsum</p>
           <p>lorem</p>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for taking some time @Programmer21 but this snippet returns all the elements, not just the searched for "Lorem" keyword.  I also don't understand why you have two inputs "keyword" and "keyword2" when there's only one search input?